# PRC-Tools For MS-DOS

Tags: dos, palm-os, palm, prc-tools

I'm emulating MS-DOS 6.22 with [PocketDOS](http://pocketdos.com/), but I want to develop for Palm OS on it, then I want to know if I can run [prc-tools](http://prc-tools.sourceforge.net/) or any other compiler for Palm OS on it.

Comment: Have you just tried doing so?  Perhaps superuser is a better place to ask this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never saw a port of prc-tools to run in a strict DOS environment.  The Windows versions of them were built on top of the cygwin framework.  It's possible that you could build it using DJGPP, but I suspect that much of the code, libraries, and utilities rely on having more than 8.3 characters in filenames.

The other key tools were all Windows, Mac, or Linux based.  By the time Palm OS development really started, DOS just wasn't an environment professional programmers were using for programming.

You could try running Mini vMac from http://jpdefault.altervista.org/?p=software&id=minivmac and then using an old version of CodeWarrior for Palm OS.  Version 6 still had support for 68K hosts, IIRC.